# Error: 0xC002F210 (can't import a database in my SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2014 installed on my PC, working on a same project in my company, a worker send me a database to import.

I followed the steps described [here](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/oschulte/summer2011/assignments/a2/mdb2SQLServer.pdf), but I get this error :

> Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[~TMPCLP14521] (
>   [Champ1] nvar..." failed with the following error: "Culture is not supported.
>   Parameter name: culture
>   3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier.".
>
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

What is wrong?

Comment: Rather than linking us to an off-site resource (and ask us to download a file from a stranger) post what you did in your post. Your error appears to implying you used SSIS to import the database; which seems odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved , after reading  [this issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172903/microsoft-sql-server-local-report-culture-is-not-supported-3072-is-invalide-cul) i found that in order to make the import work ,apparently ,the sqlserver and the system should have the same language format ;

My Sql Server is in french ,my windows was in english format changing it to french format in setting>region>region format solved my problem.